# Question on Heavy-Tailed Distribution

Tags: probability, stochastic-calculus, expected-value

> Consider a random variable $\max_{s<1} B_s$, where $B_s$ is a standard Brownian motion. If we take its expectation we have that $\mathbb{E}[\max_{s<1} B_s]=+\infty$.

This condition, however, does not make the distribution heavy-tailed, which I am confused over. I feel I am overlooking an obvious fact.

Comment: Are you sure that expectation is infinite?

Comment: I believe so, as there is no restriction to the range of values taken by the Brownian motion at time $s$, but I could be wrong

Comment: I think that value is finite. The fact that the maximum can take arbitrary values doesn't mean that the expectation should be infinite. Think simply of a gaussian distributed variable... surely not heavy tailed...